# Are the double forward/backward pipe operators documented?

Tags: f#

I remember reading about the double pipe operators -- ||> and <|| -- somewhere and now I can't remember where. I can't find them on MSDN or in the language spec. Are they documented anywhere?

Example

```
let print a b = sprintf "%O %O" a b
(1, 2) ||> print
// val it : string = "1 2"
```

Comment: For those interested, there are also triple forward/backward pipe operators: |||> and <|||

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Double (forward/backward) pipe operators are documented in the list of [F# operators on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx) and are also documented as a function exported from the [`Core.Operators` module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353754.aspx).

This is probably automatically generated from the XML documentation in the F# sources, so the pages have somewhat cryptic names:

- [Operators.( ||> )<'T1,'T2,'U> Function (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340237.aspx)
- [Operators.( <|| )<'T1,'T2,'U> Function (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370400.aspx)

As a side-note, finding the operator using search engines is a bit of a problem, so I looked in the F# sources (distributed with CTP release) and the `prim-types.fs` includes the following:

```
/// <summary>Apply a function to two values, the 
///   values being a pair on the left, the function on the right</summary>
/// <param name="arg1">The first argument.</param>
/// <param name="arg2">The second argument.</param>
/// <param name="func">The function.</param>
/// <returns>The function result.</returns>
val inline (||>): arg1:'T1 * arg2:'T2 -> func:('T1 -> 'T2 -> 'U) -> 'U
```

I was going to recommend the F# sources as a good documentation for this kind of thing (which they certainly are), but then I pasted a part of the `<summary>` tag to google and found the pages mentioned above :-).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think to look in the sources.

Comment: @Tomas At some point in the last five years, they seem to have added the double pipe operators to the MSDN list of F# operators :) Edited your post to reflect that update.

Answer (score 1):

See @Tomas' answer.  The key aspect is that these are merely functions in the library, so you want to look in the library docs (and [Core.Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353754(v=VS.100).aspx) contains these guys).